# resize image before copy?

Tags: php, image

I'm using the PHP copy function to copy an image after upload to a directory.  Is there a way to resize the image before I copy it? I need to resize it to 80x80 for use in my forum.

Here is how I'm calling my copy:

```
//lets move a copy to the img dir for the forum
$avatar_tmp_file = 'forum/img/avatars/'.$_SESSION['forum_uid']. '.jpg';
copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $avatar_tmp_file);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do so. using imagick for instance.

```
$image=new Imagick();
$image->readImage($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$image->thumbnailImage(80,80);
$image->writeImage($avatar_tmp_file);
```